# segmentation fault on fprintf in Dev-C++

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dev-c++

Specifically what can be causing a segmentation fault at a fprintf call. The fprintf call is below. If there are too many possibilities that can cause this then please provide a generalized set of causes.

```
status = printf("Processing %u by %u image.  Please wait...\n", 3, 3);
```

When I debug my program "main.c" (.c not .cpp) the segmentation fault occurs and I get two prompts stating there is a segmentation fault by Dev-C++. status is set to 12 which corresponds to the first "3".

I am more interested in the Computer Science theory of handling this problem. If that is possible?

Edit:

What is the list of possible bugs that cause segmentation faults?

Is code review/ analysis the only way to find the problem?

Are there debugger tools that can do this and how do they work (in short)?

Comment: Post complete source code.

Comment: Its not possible to answer this in general?

Comment: The general answer is "segfaults are caused by memory access". The problem is that the part of your code that's causing it may not be what you expect.

Comment: Ok, so the segmentation fault may have nothing to do with the printf call? Does the fault occur due to some background process that picked up the error from an earlier line? I'd like to know if and possible how this could be? Thanks

Comment: I dare to say that the code segment you posted can't be the reason for the segmentation fault. You've probably got a memory error (buffer overrun or something) earlier in your program and it's simply random that it crashes at the printf line. The best thing you can do is to step through the code using a debugger and observe memory allocations etc.

Comment: A list of things that cause segmentation faults would be useful then. Is that possible? I know of writing outside the end of a string or trying to use a bad pointer address (I think). What else is there?

Comment: How do you observe the memory allocations? Perhaps I should add these questions to the main question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With mingw and gdb, I have found that unless you are using [Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028), that when the program halts, and where the error occurs, have basically no relation to each other whatsoever.  With it running, however, I have found it to be pretty reliable at finding the problem.